# Get new value of entity field after Doctrine flush

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to resize an image after persisting an entity with Doctrine. In my Entity code, I'm setting a field to a specific value before the flush and the update :

```
 /**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->getFile()) {
        // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
        $filename = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $this->image = $filename.'.png';
    }
}
```

So the image field is supposed to be updated.
Then in my controller, I'd like to do my resize job:

```
if ($form->isValid()) 
    {
        $em->persist($activite);
        $em->flush();

        //resize the image
        $img_path = $activite->getImage();
        resizeImage($img_path);
    }
```

However, at this point in the code, the value of $activite->image is still null. How can I get the new value?

(Everything is saved well in the database.)

Comment: Image path must already exist when you call.
Try, if you have not already done so, insert it in a var_dump() to see if there is or not.
For security will also clear the cache, it should not serve in theory, but it can not hurt!

Comment: After clearing the cache, var_dump returns null.I have tried to get my entity from the DB just after the flush thanks to the ID but the image field is still null.

Comment: Are you sure that the database is saved to the path of the image?
You said you run the query with the id, you will recover so `$activite->getId()`, so if id is present it must also be the path to the image, except that this path is not present ..
I tried to reproduce what you are doing and to me it works properly.

Answer (score 4):

The `EntityManager` has a  `refresh()` method to update your entity with the latest values from database.

```
$em->refresh($entity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my error.

Actually, I was following this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

and at some point they give this code to set the file:

```
 public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    // check if we have an old image path
    if (isset($this->path)) {
        // store the old name to delete after the update
        $this->temp = $this->path;
        $this->path = null;
    } else {
        $this->path = 'initial';
    }
}
```

And then after the upload, in the first version (with the random filename), they do :

```
$this->file = null;
```

But then in the second version, this code is replace by:

```
$this->setFile(null);
```

My problem is that I've tried the two versions to finally come back to the first. However, I forgot to change the line to set the file to null and so everytime my path field was reset to null.

Sorry for this absurdity and thanks for your help.